# System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. within c#

Tags: c#

I execute the following script order to send mail automatically but I got error. I checked the variable format htmlMessageFrom and AlertEmail_SendCc and there are in good format.

```
 public void Main()
    {

        string htmlMessageFrom = Dts.Variables["User::AlertEmail_From"].Value.ToString();
        string htmlMessageTo = Dts.Variables["User::AlertEmail_SendCc"].Value.ToString();
        string htmlMessageSubject = Dts.Variables["User::AlertEmail_Subject"].Value.ToString();
        String SmtpServer = Dts.Connections["smtp_Server"].Properties["SmtpServer"].GetValue(Dts.Connections["smtp_Server"]).ToString();
         SendMailMessage(htmlMessageFrom, htmlMessageTo, htmlMessageSubject, true, SmtpServer);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }

    private void SendMailMessage(string From, string SendTo, string Subject, bool IsBodyHtml, string Server)
    {

        MailMessage htmlMessage;
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient;

        htmlMessage = new MailMessage(From, SendTo, Subject, " " );  
        htmlMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml;

        mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(Server);

        mySmtpClient.Send(htmlMessage);


    } 
}
```

**Error:**

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: The
>   specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. at
>   System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32&
>   offset, String& displayName) at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.ParseValue(String addresses) at
>   System.Net.Mail.Message..ctor(String from, String to) at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage..ctor(String from, String to) at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage..ctor(String from, String to, String
>   subject, String body) at
>   ST_562e700b307e4f0a90da378d13a4c608.csproj.ScriptMain.SendMailMessage(String
>   From, String SendTo, String Subject, Boolean IsBodyHtml, String
>   Server) at
>   ST_562e700b307e4f0a90da378d13a4c608.csproj.ScriptMain.Main() --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: either of your email `From` or `SendTo` are not in correct format.

Comment: So what is the value of the email address when it barfs

Comment: the variable format htmlMessageFrom and AlertEmail_SendCc and there are in good format.

Comment: The exception seems pretty self-explanatory - Have you debugged your code to confirm that the email address parameters you are passing into your method are valid email addresses?

Comment: So `MailMessage` seems to disagree that your addresses are valid. Do you use real addresses or test addresses that you could post here? So we could see what it is that the parser does not like.

Comment: @RenéVogt all addresses mails are in real but it is about 36 mails addresses.

Comment: So you have a single valid email address in `From` and a list of comma separated valid email addresses in `SendTo`?

Comment: @spodger yes exactly

Comment: No problem, then. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I resolve the problem

```
 private void SendMailMessage(string From, string SendTo, string Subject, string Body, bool IsBodyHtml, string Server) 
        {

            MailMessage htmlMessage;
            SmtpClient mySmtpClient;

            htmlMessage = new MailMessage(From, SendTo, Subject, Body);  
            htmlMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml;
            foreach (var address in SendTo.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                htmlMessage.To.Add(address);
            }

            mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(Server);
            mySmtpClient.Send(htmlMessage);

        }
```

Comment: The only change to your constructor call is that you are now passing a `Body` when you didn't before. I am quite surprised that that somehow made the `From` and/or `SendTo` valid.

Comment: It is also unclear why you are setting the `To` twice - once in the constructor, and then by `Add`ing.

Comment: May I recommend that you set the "To" address at the point of construction to be the From address, then do the loop through adding the SendTo addresses split from the list one by one?
Depending on your scenario you may wish to add the addresses to the BCC field if you don't want everyone to know the full distribution list contact details.